# Dynamics CRM/Dynamics 365 Apply solution upgrade programmatically

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

There is a set of rules that should be applied while moving solutions from one instance to another, so there is an idea to use a custom tool that will make all changes, export and import solutions to another instance. The question is next:

***How could "solution upgrade applying" be implemented with C#?***

Importing "as holding" easily could be done by setting (CRM 2016 SDK)

```
 var import = new ImportSolutionRequest();
 import.HoldingSolution = true;
```

this allows to have a holding solution in a target environment, but after some tests we still can't "Apply" this upgrade for the previously installed solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have imported the holding solution you can upgrade it using a `DeleteAndPromoteRequest`.

A basic example:

```
public Guid UpgradeSolution(string solutionUniqueName, IOrganizationService service)
{
    var request = new DeleteAndPromoteRequest
    {
        UniqueName = solutionUniqueName
    };

    var response = (DeleteAndPromoteResponse)service.Execute(request);
    return response.SolutionId;
}
```

In the `DeleteAndPromoteResponse` the `SolutionId` property holds the `Guid` of the promoted solution.